# Oracle: get the range from id column for every nth record

Tags: oracle11g

Is it possible to get the range of values for a number column every nth record, in Oracle?

```
For example:
I have a column named ID that have value 2,4,7,8,9,11,14,17,20...

I wanted to get the start and end value for the range:
2,8
9,17
20,... so on.
```

what can I achieve this inside Oracle?
I tried mod value, nth_value but it does not give range.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 2 id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 7 id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 8 id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 9 id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 11 id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 14 id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 17 id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 20 id FROM dual)
SELECT MIN(id) start_id,
       MAX(id) end_id
FROM   (SELECT id,
               ceil(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id)/4) grp
        FROM   your_table)
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY start_id;

  START_ID     END_ID
---------- ----------
         2          8
         9         17
        20         20
```

This works by taking the row number of each row in id order, dividing that by 4 and then finding the ceiling of that number to produce an integer. This means that the first 4 rows will end up with 1 as the grp value, the 2nd 4 rows will end up with 2 as the grp value, etc.

Then it's a simple matter of finding the min/max ids per grp.

Comment: super....works perfect...I was trying partition, first_value, last_value and didn't get the expected value.